# Global Property for MDI application

Tags: properties, mdi

I have just completed an MDI application. But now I'm trying to create a property that I'll be able to set and have it persist through all child forms. On the Parent form I have the following code.

```
Private userrole As String

Public Property userrole() As String
    Get
        Return userrole
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        userrole = value
    End Set
End Property
```

But I can't set the property from any of the other forms. I'm relatively new to .NET previous apps have been in Access but management wants the access apps migrated to .NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a simple mistake in spelling. userrole vs usrrole.

Using the above method I can call form1.userrole.ToString and get the value of the variable.
form1.userrole() =  sets it.

I told you I was new. ;)
Thanks for letting me be a part of this forum.